# Elasticsearch failing to run

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch in a Ubuntu 18.04 VM that worked the first time I installed it. But after a reboot, it can't start anymore. The Java version is:

openjdk version "1.8.0_252"

the status of the elasticsearch service is as follows:

```
systemctl status elasticsearch
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-05-07 21:46:51 EDT; 8min ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 1484 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1484 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 07 21:46:51 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[1484]:         at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
May 07 21:46:51 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[1484]:         at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
May 07 21:46:51 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[1484]:         at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
May 07 21:46:51 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[1484]:         at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
May 07 21:46:51 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[1484]:         at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
May 07 21:46:51 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[1484]:         at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
May 07 21:46:51 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[1484]:         at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
May 07 21:46:51 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[1484]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:60)
May 07 21:46:51 BW_Test_VM systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 07 21:46:51 BW_Test_VM systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have adjusted the /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options file to 512m, 1g and 4g but still can't work.

journalctl -u elasticsearch shows the following output:

May 08 12:09:38 BW_Test_VM systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
May 08 12:09:38 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20437]: warning: Falling back to java on path. This behavior is deprecated. Specify JAVA_HOME
May 08 12:09:38 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20437]: /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-env: line 79: cd: /etc/elasticsearch: Permission denied
May 08 12:09:38 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20437]: Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/jvm.options
May 08 12:09:38 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20437]:         at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
May 08 12:09:38 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20437]:         at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
May 08 12:09:38 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20437]:         at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
May 08 12:09:38 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20437]:         at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
May 08 12:09:38 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20437]:         at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
May 08 12:09:38 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20437]:         at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
May 08 12:09:38 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20437]:         at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
May 08 12:09:38 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20437]:         at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
May 08 12:09:38 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20437]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:60)
May 08 12:09:38 BW_Test_VM systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 08 12:09:38 BW_Test_VM systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 08 12:10:22 BW_Test_VM systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
May 08 12:10:22 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20782]: warning: Falling back to java on path. This behavior is deprecated. Specify JAVA_HOME
May 08 12:10:22 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20782]: /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-env: line 79: cd: /etc/elasticsearch: Permission denied
May 08 12:10:23 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20782]: Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/jvm.options
May 08 12:10:23 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20782]:         at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
May 08 12:10:23 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20782]:         at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
May 08 12:10:23 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20782]:         at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
May 08 12:10:23 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20782]:         at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
May 08 12:10:23 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20782]:         at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
May 08 12:10:23 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20782]:         at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
May 08 12:10:23 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20782]:         at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
May 08 12:10:23 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20782]:         at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
May 08 12:10:23 BW_Test_VM elasticsearch[20782]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:60)
May 08 12:10:23 BW_Test_VM systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 08 12:10:23 BW_Test_VM systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

I see the warning "Permission denied, but I'm a superuser and the folder is owned by root.

Any idea on what might be wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Check elasticsearch logs.

Comment: Can you run `journalctl -u elasticsearch` and add the output to your question? Make sure to remove the `--quiet` option from the ExecStart command line in the `elasticsearch.service` file first.

Comment: Here's the requested output output (journalctl -u elasticsearch)

Answer (score 0):

ok, I re-installed elasticsearch and this time the system works well after several reboots. Sorry, no RFO, maybe some misconfiguration during the installation process.